# Spring mapping request params to object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot and I have to write function, that takes a lot a parameters:

```
public ResponseEntity function(
@RequestParam("page") Integer page,
@RequestParam("size) Integer size,
@RequestParam("name") String name,
@RequestParam("groups") String name) {
....
}
```

I dont like this method signature (as there is a lot more parameters than 4) and I **can't use @RequestBody**.

I tried creating a special Object

```
public ParamHandler {
private int age;
private int size;
private String name;
private Group[] groups;
}
```

And then

```
public ResponseEntity(ParamHadler ph) {....}
```

However, as you see I need to cast String "groups" to array of object Group. Spring can't do this automatically. So I tried to write custom Jackson deserializer for ParamHandler. Obviously, it doesn't help as @RequestParam hardly connected wit JSON.

So I want to know how can override Spring's object mapper for request params? Any other techniques will also be appriciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean `Group[] groups` in the fourth parameter of the first example? --- You also say *"as you see I need to cast"*, but I don't see any cast in the code.

Comment: Yes, I meant this. I mean I have a string as a request parameter, which is names of groups splitted by comma. I have to write some logic in object mapper to have an object out of this

Comment: you're probably mistaken in design. this ParamHandler is Input DTO, and you do not have to parse it's value to split (although, you probably could). Instead this DTO should just recieve and you should split it with helper service later when you need(save) it.

Comment: if it's splitted by comma, you would not be able to do it with json out of box, so split responsibilities: one object recieves, one parses recieved object into entity, entity, and service that will find group by name (as you have comma separated list, right?)

Comment: Thank you. However I am still interested how Spring maps this parameters to object? Does it just searches for property or setter with the same name?